# Joomla BuildRule adds language code at the back of setPath

Tags: joomla-3.x, jroute, system-plugin, router

I'm having a problem with building the rule for a particular URL. Here's what I have in my system plugin:

```
//...
function onAfterInitialise() {
    require_once '/path/to/myhelper.php';
    $router = $this->app->getRouter();
    $router->attachBuildRule(array('MyHelper', 'BuildRoute'));
    $router->attachParseRule(array('MyHelper', 'ParseRoute'));
}
//...
```

In the myhelper.php:

```
class MyHelper {
     //...
     public static function buildRoute(&$router, &$uri) {
         $uri->setPath('foobar');
         $uri->setQuery(array());
     }
     //...
}
```

In another file, when I try to `JRoute` any url, it adds the language code at the *end* instead of the *beginning*. For example:

```
echo JRoute::_('helloworld.php');
//this will print "/foobar/en/" instead of just "/en/foobar/" or possibly just "/foobar"
```

A few things:

1. I have the Joomla system plugin `System - Language Filter` enabled.
2. Setting `Remove URL Language Code` to either Yes or No does not change the outcome.
3. Disabling the plugin will remove the language code, but I can't do that.
4. The baffling part is, all other Joomla generated URLs (like the ones in the menu), have the language code *in front*. eg `mydomain.com/en/mylink`
5. Also baffling is if I do not try to override the route, Joomla show the language code in the front for the same `JRoute::_('helloworld.php')`. It shows `/en/helloworld`.

Any direction on this is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Your plugin is ordered before `System - Language Filter`. Changing the plugin order should fix the issue. Otherwise you may need to pass stage argument to `attachBuildRule()` and/or `attachParseRule()`. It defines at which stage of the build/parse process the rules are applied.

```
$router = $this->app->getRouter();
$router->attachBuildRule(array('MyHelper', 'BuildRoute'), $router::PROCESS_AFTER);
```

https://api.joomla.org/cms-3/classes/Joomla.CMS.Router.Router.html#method_attachBuildRule